# setContentView from List (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I have a list of foods that also contains the layout I want inflate when it is clicked.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val food = listOf(
            Foods("Creme Brulee", "A rich egg dessert with torched sugar on top.", "French", R.drawable.cremebrulee1, R.layout.food_cremebrulee),
            Foods("Hamburger", "Something something", "Spanish", R.drawable.person2, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Grilled Cheese", "Something something", "Chinese", R.drawable.person3, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("French Onion Soup", "Something something", "French", R.drawable.person4, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Salmon", "Something something", "German", R.drawable.person2, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Fish Tacos", "Something something", "Dutch", R.drawable.person3, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Vegetable Sushi", "Something something", "Asian", R.drawable.person4, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Fried Egg", "Something something", "Thai", R.drawable.person1, R.layout.food_hamburger),
            Foods("Vinagrette", "Thai style vinagrette with peanut butter", "Indian", R.drawable.person2, R.layout.food_hamburger)
        )


        myCustomFood.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = FoodAdapter(food) {
                d("marlon", "hi from MainActivity!")
                //startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, FoodDetailView::class.java))
                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, FoodDetailView::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FoodDetailView : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView() <--- What do I put here in order to grab the appropriate R.layout when a food on the list is clicked?
    }
}
```

As you can see the first selection has R.layout.cremebrulee1 and the others are R.layout.hamburger, what do I put in setContentView in order to grab the R.layout from the list?

Answer (score 4):

You can put your layout id in extras:

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, FoodDetailView::class.java)
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_LAYOUT", food.layout)
startActivity(intent)
```

And then get it back in you target activity:

```
val layoutId = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_LAYOUT", 0)
if (layoutId > 0) {
    setContentView(layoutId)
}
```